# Cónexion con PHP a MySQL Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, indexeddb

estoy reempezando ausar php, la última vez que lo use fue hace años, y estoy haciendo una conexión, esto por la universidad, el problema es que el docente que nos explico eso solo copio su código, y aunque le entiendo más o menos, hay cosas en las que me pierdo, y cuando intento guardar un registro me muestra el error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\Programacion_Computacional_IV\primer_proyecto\modules\clis\cli.php:31 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Programacion_Computacional_IV\primer_proyecto\modules\clis\cli.php(25): cli->record_data() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Programacion_Computacional_IV\primer_proyecto\modules\clis\cli.php(19): cli->validate_data() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\Programacion_Computacional_IV\primer_proyecto\modules\clis\cli.php(8): cli->get_data('{"show_msg":fal...') #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Programacion_Computacional_IV\primer_proyecto\modules\clis\cli.php on line 31

Lo que intento es conectar a mysql, pero tambien hago uso de indexDB, porque así nos lo enseño el docente y, no se si la la conexión depende de indexDB, esa parte no me quedo clara, y he estado investigando pero no logro solucionarlo, esto es lo que tengo (algunos metodos son metodos de Vuejs pero debido a que mi problema no recide en los componentes solo mostrare las funciones):

main.js (Crear una base de datos en indexDB y la funcion para llamarla, segun lo que entiendo).

```js
// Inicio app new Vue
        openBd() {
            let indexDB = indexedDB.open('db_sistema_a2', 1);
            indexDB.onupgradeneeded = (e) => {
                let db = e.target.result;
                tblClients = db.createObjectStore('clients', { keyPath: 'idCli' });
                tblProducts = db.createObjectStore('products', { keyPath: 'idProd' });
                tblProviders = db.createObjectStore('providers', { keyPath: 'idProv' });
                tblCategories = db.createObjectStore('categories', { keyPath: 'idCat' });

                tblClients.createIndex('idCli', 'idCli', { unique: true });
                tblProducts.createIndex('cliCode', 'cliCode', { unique: false });

                tblProviders.createIndex('idProv', 'idProv', { unique: true });
                tblProviders.createIndex('provCode', 'provCode', { unique: false });

                tblCategories.createIndex('idCat', 'idCat', { unique: true });
                tblCategories.createIndex('catCode', 'catCode', { unique: false });

                tblProducts.createIndex('idProd', 'idProd', { unique: true });
                tblProducts.createIndex('prodCode', 'prodCode', { unique: false });
            };
            indexDB.onsuccess = (e) => {
                db = e.target.result;
            };
            indexDB.onerror = (e) => {
                console.log(e.target.error);
            };
        },
// Fin app
function openStore(store, mode) {
    console.log(db);
    return db.transaction(store, mode).objectStore(store);
}
```

cli.js (Llama al archivo php y envia los datos)

```js
// Inicio componente clientes
// Estructuta de cli
            cli: {
                show_msg: false,
                action: 0,
                msg: '',
                idCli: '',
                code: '',
                name: '',
                address: '',
                phone: '',
                dui: ''
            }
// Sincronizar con la base de datos de mysql
        syncClients(cli = '') {
            fetch(`modules/clis/cli.php?cli=${JSON.stringify(cli)}&action=get_data`, 
            {credentials: 'same-origin'})
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.cli.msg = 'Cliente procesado con exito';
            }).catch(err => {
                this.cli.msg = 'Error al procesar el cliente';
            });
        },
// Guardar cambios
saveCli(){
            let action = ['registrado', 'actualizado', 'eliminado'];
            if (this.cli.action == 0) {
                this.cli.idCli = genDateId();
            }
            let store = openStore('clients', 'readwrite'),
                request = store.put(this.cli);
            console.log(request);
            request.onsuccess = (e) => {
                this.syncClients(this.cli);
                this.cli.show_msg = true;
                this.newCli(); // Vacia los campos en el componente
                this.getData(''); // Muestra los datos de la base de datos (me da el mismo error)
                this.cli.msg = `Se a ${action[this.cli.action]} correctamente el cliente`;
            };
            request.onerror = (e) => {
                this.cli.msg = 'Error al procesar el cliente';
            };
        },
// Fin del componente
```

db.php

```php
<?php
class db {
    private $conex, $result;

    public function db($server, $user, $pass,) {
        $this->conex = new PDO($server, $user, $pass, array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)) or die("Error en la conexión");
        return $this->conex;
    }
    public function query($sql) {
        try {
            $params = func_get_args();
            array_shift($params);
            print_r($params);
            print_r($sql);
            $this->ready = $this->conex->prepare($sql);
            $this->result = $this->ready->execute($params);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    public function get_data() {
        return $this->ready->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
    public function get_result() {
        return $this->result;
    }
    public function get_last_id() {
        return $this->conex->lastInsertId();
    }
}
?>
```

config.php

```php
<?php
include("db.php");
$conex = new db('localhost:81', 'root', '');
?>
```

cli.php (Empiezo diciendo que para mi, db nunca se define, y cuando pregunte por eso mi docente me respondio que en la clase cli, la funcion cli se ejecuta al momento de llamar a la clase, porque se llama igual a la clase, o al menos eso entendí)

```php
<?php
include('../../private/db/config.php');

extract($_REQUEST);

$class_client = new cli($conex);
$cli = isset($cli) ? $cli: '[]';
print_r(json_encode($class_client->$action($cli)));

class cli {
    private $data = [], $db;

    public $result = ['msg'=>'Ready'];
    public function cli($db = '') {
        $this->db = $db;
    }
    public function get_data($cli = '') {
        $this->data = json_decode($cli, true);
        return $this->validate_data();
    }
    public function validate_data() {
        if (empty(trim($this->data['idCli'])) || empty(trim($this->data['code'])) || empty(trim($this->data['name'])) || empty(trim($this->data['address'])) || empty(trim($this->data['phone'])) || empty(trim($this->data['dui']))) {
            $this->result['msg'] = 'Por favor complete todos los campos';
        }
        return $this->record_data();
    }
    private function record_data() {
        if($this->result['msg'] == 'Ready') {
            if($this->data['action'] == 0) {
                print_r($this->db); // La siguiente línea es la número 31
                $this->db->query('INSERT INTO db_sistema_a2.clients (idCli, cliCode, cliName, cliAddress, cliPhone, cliDNI) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', $this->data['idCli'], $this->data['code'], $this->data['name'], $this->data['address'], $this->data['phone'], $this->data['dui']);
                return $this->db->get_last_id();
            } else if ($this->data['action'] == 1) {
                $this->db->query('UPDATE db_sistema_a2.clients SET cliCode = ?, cliName = ?, cliAddress = ?, cliPhone = ?, cliDNI = ? WHERE idCli = ?', $this->data['code'], $this->data['name'], $this->data['address'], $this->data['phone'], $this->data['dui'], $this->data['idCli']);
                return $this->db->get_result();
            } else if ($this->data['action'] == 2) {
                $this->db->query('DELETE FROM db_sistema_a2.clients WHERE idCli = ?', $this->data['idCli']);
                return $this->db->get_result();
            }
        } else {
            return $this->result['msg'];
        }
    }
    public function get_records() {
        $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM db_sistema_a2.clients');
        return $this->db->get_result();
    }
}
?>
```

Hasta antes de `$this->db->query`, en la función `recod_data` de `cli.php`, recibo algo como esto

> {"show_msg":false,"action":0,"msg":"Error al procesar el cliente","idCli":"62317e3a","code":"000","name":"aaa","address":"aaa","phone":"9999-9999","dui":"99999999-9"}get_data

Intenté cambiar el nombre de la funcion `cli` en `cli.php` por `__construct` y en este caso ahora db si recibia un valor, pero me arrojaba el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in

Pero al menos si accede a la conexión, y cuando hago eso si recibo los parametros y sql, pero no los ejecuta, recibo algo como esto:

> Array ( [0] => 62317fe2 [1] => 000 [2] => aaa [3] => aaa [4] => 9999-9999 [5] => 99999999-9 )
> INSERT INTO db_sistema_a2.clients (idCli, cliCode, cliName, cliAddress, cliPhone, cliDNI) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Ya he hecho conexiones, pero ninguna como esta, ayuda, aclarar que no es de urgencia, no es ninguna actividad solo quiero entenderle, de antemano, muchas gracias.

Comment: Al parecer, cuando haces `new cli($conex);`, la variable `$conex` es _null_. Lo que podría significar que no se ejecuto el archivo `config.php`. En `PHP v8` esta deprecado el uso de métodos constructores con el mismo nombre de la clase ([Mas info](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.decon.php)).

Comment: Cambie las funciones `cli` y `db` a `__construct` de los archivos `cli.php` y `db.php` respectivamente, y le arrojo el siguiente error: 
`Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in`, luego decidi cambiar la información del servidor a  `mysql:host=localhost:81;charset=utf8`, pero no respondia, cambie al puerto 80, con mariaDB y ya me funcionó, muchas gracías por aclararme el punto del construct @Marcos